# ubuntu 10.10 - Get rid of the Desktop directory in home

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I deleted `/home/user/Desktop` because I don't put anything on the Desktop.
Unfortunately the directory keeps reappearing.

What I tried so far is to replace `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`
with `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=""` in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, but it didn't help.

I'm pretty sure I locked down the desktop completely in an earlier install, but I can't remember how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some of the programs you're using recreates it everytime you run it... maybe nautilus uses it for default folder, or for example firefox as a default download place, or something similar..?

*edit:* well, i'm not exactly sure [**this**](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=408896#10) will work because it's quite old, but it still might put you on the right track...

Comment: It's probably nautilus, but how can I turn it off?

Comment: edited the answer, give it a try... =)

Comment: Thanks [pootzko](http://superuser.com/users/46775/pootzko). Apparently there was a bug report and subsequent fix in 2007 (--no-desktop). Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to set these variables to non-empty values. The directories will be created somewhere, but they can be out of sight.

```
$ grep DESKTOP ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/.xdg/Desktop"
```

(works for me on Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: Thanks [Gilles](http://superuser.com/users/42315/gilles), I did just that and it works. I'm concerned however that some day I accidentally drop something on the desktop and wonder where it went because I don't remember where I hid the folder:-).